# Changing customer portal user profiles in Salesforce using Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a portal user and two profiles assigned to the portal.
I want to run a trigger to change the profile whenever some conditions are met.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Although [DML is forbidden](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm) on the Profile object itself, you can change the profile of a user (from the Apex developer's guide):

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com',
   EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
   LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, // <--- 
   TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');

System.runAs(u) 
{
    // The following code runs as user 'u'
    System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
    System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.runAs(u) only used in Test Classes, for Apex classes you cannot write the above code